# Spring Java @Scheduling configuration

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-java-config, spring-scheduled

Using @Scheduling to run method at  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000) and set up @Scheduling threading by implementing SchedulingConfigurer

```
    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    }
```

if I used Thread.sleep or Lock , no other thread is created by Executor unless Thread.sleep wake up or lock is cleared.

Can someone explain internal working if i have 10 pool size they 10 threads should be created at rate of 10000 millisec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically such behavior comes from `ScheduledExecutorService` implementation which is used internally by spring. If you will run this code you will notice the same behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    executor.schedule(() -> {
        System.out.println("Running task in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted while sleeping");
        }
    }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

When you submit task to scheduled thread pool it is wrapped with `RunnableScheduledFuture` which is passed to `delayedExecute` method. This method adds the task to the tasks queue and starts new worker if current number of workers is less than `corePoolSize`. Worker tries to get a task from the queue and process it invoking `run` method. There is a dedicated `DelayedWorkQueue` implementation which returns tasks only if they are ready for execution. Here is how `run` method of `RunnableScheduledFuture` looks like:

```
    /**
     * Overrides FutureTask version so as to reset/requeue if periodic.
     */
    public void run() {
        boolean periodic = isPeriodic();
        if (!canRunInCurrentRunState(periodic))
            cancel(false);
        else if (!periodic)
            ScheduledFutureTask.super.run();
        else if (ScheduledFutureTask.super.runAndReset()) {
            setNextRunTime();
            reExecutePeriodic(outerTask);
        }
    }
```

As you can see it invokes actual task logic in `runAndReset`, calculates the next running time and submits the same updated task to the queue again (`reExecutePeriodic` is almost the same as `schedule`). There is only a single periodic task for all executions which is resubmitted again and again with updated time after the previous execution is finished. So such thread pool runs only a single instance of each task type in any given moment and scales only for different type of tasks.

If you are interesting in how spring schedules tasks take a look at `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` class and particularly at `scheduleFixedDelayTask` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you use threadpool:
By default you going to have 10 threads in your pool(already initialized). The first time that @scheduled is executed, this function is going to execute in a thread from your pool (now remaining 9 threads), if the function yet finished and @scheduled is executed again, your function going to executed in other thread from you your pool, so now you have 8 thread remaining in your pool. (8 idle, 2 running threads)

If you aren`t use threadpool only one thread is used.

spring documentation:

> If you do not provide a 'pool-size' attribute, the default thread pool
>   will only have a single thread. There are no other configuration
>   options for the scheduler.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Agree , but what I observe is that , if I used Thread.sleep or lock inside @scheduled method for pool-size 10 then only one time thread is executed of it is locked permanently. Let say 1 thread is executed at scheduled method from pool of 10, and 1 thread stuck in lock, then other 9 thread won't executed for scheduled method method. all stuck . Even if i used Sleep.

Comment: Can you share a gist with your code?, Because looks like the code is using single thread.

Comment: only @Async need to be added with schedule annotation.